# What is recession? Two quarters of -ve GDP or two quarters of slowing GDP?

Tags: gdp

I'm confused with the definition of recession. Is it two quarters of negative GDP growth , meaning GDP growing at -1% and -2% or GDP slowing to 2% and 1.5%.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, a recession is not defined in this way in any case. If it were, it would be negative growth, and not a decline in productivity.

In the US, the [NBER US Business Cycle Expansion and Contractions data](https://www.nber.org/research/data/us-business-cycle-expansions-and-contractions) defines a recession. The [committee has determined](https://www.nber.org/news/business-cycle-dating-committee-announcement-july-19-2021)

> "that a trough in monthly economic activity occurred in the US economy
> in April 2020. The previous peak in economic activity occurred in
> February 2020. The recession lasted two months, which makes it the
> shortest US recession on record."

Following this definition, the recession was declared over before the second quarter even occurred.There has also been a period where 2 consecutive quarters of decline were not defined as a recession. Most probably, the first two quarters this year (2022) will also not be declared a recession.

See this [question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/52205/37817) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Negative growth.  Though I suspect this question will be quickly closed :)